# What does "made sad sense" here mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Michael’s funeral was strange because his father didn’t cry. And three
> months later he left Michael’s mom. At least according to Dave at
> lunchtime. I think about it sometimes. I wonder what went on in
> Michael’s house around dinner and TV shows. Michael never left a note
> or at least his parents didn’t let anyone see it. Maybe it was
> “problems at home.” I wish I knew. It might make me miss him more
> clearly. It might have **made sad sense.**
>
> —The Perks of Being a Wallflower

What does "make sad sense" mean here?I think saying *something make sense* here doesn't connect:Charlie was talking about knowing the reason of Michael killing himself per se would make sense? It feels odd....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To "make sense," as a phrase, means to be understandable or comprehensible; in other words. "Sense" is used in this context, means "a satisfactory meaning."

"Sad" in this case modifies "sense," so "sad sense" means something like "a sad but understandable meaning" or "a reasonable but depressing rationale."

The narrator is saying, essentially:

- I don't understand why Michael killed himself.
- I don't know what Michael's home life was like, but his parents' behavior suggests that it was not a loving home, and it might even have been abusive.
- If I had known the details of what went on in Michael's home, I might be able to understand the reason why Michael killed himself.
- I know that, in that case, the reason would be a depressing one, but I would rather know anyway.

So: "It might have made sad sense" means something along the lines of: "There might have been a good, but depressing, reason for Michael to kill himself."

Answer (score 0):

AS you know the word "Sense" means feeling about sth, and here, as the text goes, make sense can't have a meaning in Phrasal form. So, at least to me , this "made sad sense" means "I felt sad about it" and the reason writer has used this phrase is to make you feel it more, by the word "sense ".

Comment: No; this is not idiomatic. When the text reads "make sense," even where there is an adjective modifying "sense," a native speaker will always read that in the meaning of "make sense": to be comprehensible or understandable.